# A trivial vector bundle with a riemannian metric has an isomorphism with the trivial bundle that is an isometry on each fiber.

Tags: differential-topology

The problem:

Demonstrate that If  $\xi^n=(E,\Pi,M)$ is a trival vector bundle with a riemannian metric, then there exist an isomorphism $\psi:E\to$ M x $R^n$ Such that $\psi $ is an isometry on each fiber.

What I have got:

Since $\xi^n$ is a trivial bundle I have an isomorphism $\psi:E\to$ M x $R^n$.

The Riemannian metric gives me an inner product on each fiber. So i can define a norm and find with Gram-Schmidt an ortonormal basis for each fibre, And construct an isometry with $\psi$  and a coordinate transformation. But i dont underestand why it would result in a vector bundle isomorphism.

I would appreciate a lot any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the Gram-Schmidt process is continuous (it is even smooth if this makes sense). Your vector bundle isomorphism will give you $n$ sections that form a basis of $E_x$ for each $x\in M$. If you apply the Gram-Schmidt process to this you will get $n$ smooth sections that are orthonormal at each point $x\in M$. This gives an isometry with the trivial bundle with the standard inner product.

Comment: Thank You!! I will work on that idea.